# Multilingual Office 365 App

Tags: javascript, ms-office, office365, multilingual, office-app

I want to write an app for Office 365 with the JavaScript API. Now I have some trouble with making it available in multiple languages. I did not found an official statement how to implement this.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some localization options available to you, such as:

- Evaluating Context.displayLanguage
- Setting locale-specific html pages in the SourceLocation element in the manifest
- Use Ajax to provide separate client script files for each locale

See the guidelines here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/fp161083.aspx

Answer (score 1):

When you build an Office 365 App, you can follow the same practice to build multi-lingual apps in ASP.NET MVC Apps. where you have all languages in resource files and load the perspective language based on user's preferences in the views.

Here is some links how to implement this:

http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx

http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-date-time.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526827/MVC-Basic-Site-Step-Multilingual-Site-Skeleton

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My mindset was not correct, so your ideas should work well but I was looking for a JS solution.